# Select query in MySql table

Tags: java, mysql

I have two tables table1 which has id(primary key)and table2 which has an name, id(foreign key). All ids are null initially in table2. Now whenever a new id is generated in parent table we have to select the very first row from table2 which has id null and update that row with the new id. Now `select * from table2 where id is null` fetches a set of rows but is there a way to modify this sql query so that it fetches me the very first row of table2 where id column is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from table2 where id is null limit 1
```

Limit specifies number of records you want to fetch.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id is null LIMIT (n - 1), 1
```

example:
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id is null LIMIT 2, 1